# How to display Alert Message when back button is Pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I need to display an `Alert Message` to the user whenever he pressed `Back Button`.
I have written following code, it displays `Alert Box` for a second and then redirect. I have specified `Button` in `Alert Box`, If user `click` on `yes`, then i create `Intent`, else i want user to stay on the current activity.

Right now it displays me following error message.

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity checkout.Checkout has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{100e8093 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1080,476} that was originally added here
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
             at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
             at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
             at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:953)
```

Code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Delete Data");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?.");
    // Add the buttons
    alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
            //Here i am doing JSON Stuff
            JSONObject commandData = new JSONObject(); 

        }
    });
    alertDialog2.show();
```

Comment: Remove the super.onBackPressed(); from onBackPressed method

Comment: Thanks! let me try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment this line:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Delete Data");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?.");
    // Add the buttons
    alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
            //Here i am doing JSON Stuff
            JSONObject commandData = new JSONObject(); 

        }
    });

   alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          YourClass.super.onBackPressed();

        }
    };
    alertDialog2.show();
```