# How to show custom dialog when user click back button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to show a custom dialog when a user clicks back button in Kotlin.

I tried this code but it doesn't work, when I click the back button the custom dialog shows and then disappears

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()

    onPause()
    creatAlertDialog()

}



fun creatAlertDialog() {


    var dialogs = Dialog(this@MainActivity)
    dialogs.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialogs.setCancelable(false)
    dialogs.setContentView(R.layout.back_press)

    dialogs.btn_yes.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }

    dialogs.btn_no.setOnClickListener {
        dialogs.dismiss()
    }

    dialogs.show()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Alert Message when back button is Pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208509/how-to-display-alert-message-when-back-button-is-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete super.onBackPressed() from your onBackPressed() callback. This way you'll avoid your super class to call its onBackPressed() method and your activity will not be destroyed.

```kotlin
override fun onBackPressed() {
    creatAlertDialog()
    // whatever you want here
}
```